# Add delay before pausing audio in jQuery

Tags: jquery, audio, hover, delay

I'm trying to fade in/out an audio file when the user hovers over a div.

The fade in works, but the audio is paused before the fade out is completed.
Here is my current code:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#playmusic').hover(
        function () {
            $('#music')[0].play();
            $('#music').animate({volume: 1}, 1000);
        },
        function () {
            $('#music').animate({volume: 0}, 1000);
            $('#music')[0].pause();    
        }
    )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="playmusic">hover to hear audio</p>

<audio id="music" preload="auto">
     <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/A_Tale_of_Distant_Lands.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I think I need to add a `.delay` into my code so the audio is paused after the fade out occurs however the following is giving me an error:

```
$('#music').delay(1000).[0].pause();
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delay the stop, can perform it with a setTimeout

Here is an example

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#music')[0].pause();
}, 1000);
```

The time is set in ms.

The **delay** function is used for jQuery effects including animations, to other thing better use **setTimeout**.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the animation's [`complete` callback](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) to pause the audio. It fires after the animation, i.e. when the audio fade is complete.

One advantage of this method over using an independent timer is that the audio is paused as soon as the animation is done, regardless of the animation's duration.

Provide the callback function using this format:

> **.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )**
>
> *complete*
> Type: Function()
> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

Or, using an [alternate format](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) to specify options:

> **.animate( properties, options )**

I also suggest using [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to prevent queuing the animations. Otherwise, the accumulation of animations can get confusing when rapidly hovering on and off the trigger.

Here's a demonstration:

```js
$(function() {

  let $music = $('#music');

  $('body').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
  });

  function playMusic() {
    $music
      .stop(true, false)
      .animate({
        volume: 1
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        start: function() {
          this.play();
        }
      });
  }

  function pauseMusic() {
    $music
      .stop(true, false)
      .animate({
        volume: 0
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function() {
          this.pause();
        }
      });
  }

  $('#playmusic').hover(
    playMusic,
    pauseMusic
  );

});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: background-color 200ms;
}

body.clicked {
  background-color: #FFFFF5;
}

#playmusic {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  background-color: #EEF;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 200ms, opacity 200ms, margin-left 200ms;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -100%;
}

body.clicked #playmusic {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 0;
}

body.clicked #playmusic:hover {
  background-color: #DDFFDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Click the page first to interact with the document.</p>
<p id="playmusic">Hover to hear audio</p>

<audio id="music" preload="auto" allow="autoplay" autoplay>
    <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/A_Tale_of_Distant_Lands.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```